# Avoiding duplicates in List within loop

Tags: c#

I have a for loop which invokes a method within it. I add the return of this method to a list however I am getting duplicates in the list (the last return from the method call is all the items in the list). Presumably this is because the `result` object is the same instance. Is there a way around this?

```
IList<CarResult> carResults = new List<CarResult>();

for (int i = 0; i < cars.Count(); i++)
{              
   result = calculation.RunForCar(
                engineSize[i],
                yearOfManufacture[i],

   carResults.Add(result);
}

   return carResults;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `RunForCar` method as well and in the code above I think you have a `)` typo.

Comment: The code provided in the question seems to be okay. You could simply the code by using the yield return statement (depending on the return type of your method). Please post the method signature and the RunForCar method as well.

Comment: Based on the behavior you are describing I guess you are re-using the `result` object inside `RunForCar()` instead of _newing_ it up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make a qualified *guess* and try to explain what's going on, without knowing exactly what's happening in your `RunForCar()`.

> Presumably this is because the result object is the same instance.

Probably yes.

Here's an example. It will not create new instances of `Foo`, but re-use the same instance over and over. So every time the name changes it changes the name on the *reference*. The `list` itself only contains the references, and therefore all the items in the `list` will be changed if you change the name on the reference.

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var result = new Foo();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    result.Name = i.ToString();
    list.Add(result);
}

foreach (var foo in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

If we instead do like the code below, we assign `result` to a *new reference*, and then we leave the existing references untouched.

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var result = new Foo();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    result = new Foo()
    {
        Name = i.ToString()
    };
    result.Name = i.ToString();
    list.Add(result);
}

foreach (var foo in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

> Is there a way around this?

Yes, you can simply create a new instance of `result` for every loop. Without knowing more about either `CarResult` or `RunForCar` I cannot say when it's best to create the new instance. But here's an example:

```
IList<CarResult> carResults = new List<CarResult>();
for (int i = 0; i < cars.Count(); i++)
{              
    result = new CarResult();
    result = calculation.RunForCar(
        engineSize[i],
        yearOfManufacture[i]); // Fixed type-o?

    carResults.Add(result);
}
return carResults;
```

Alternatively you can have a local variable inside the loop.

```
IList<CarResult> carResults = new List<CarResult>();
for (int i = 0; i < cars.Count(); i++)
{              
    var result = new CarResult(); // Will not be accessible outside of loop.
    result = calculation.RunForCar(
        engineSize[i],
        yearOfManufacture[i]); // Fixed type-o?

    carResults.Add(result);
}
return carResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result is the same instance, you need to replace IList with HashSet

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance or result object on every pass of the loop in order to avoid adding it by reference to carResults list. Oterwise, all items in carResults will hold the reference to the same object which will contain the data from the last loop cycle.